# How to get comma separated values and final value using a for loop?

Tags: php, loops, csv, concatenation, filtering

**PHP code:**

```
$b = 1;
$ab = 100;

for ($b; $b < $ab; $b++)
{
    $len = strlen($b);
    $c = 0;
    for ($c; $c < $len; $c++)
    {
        $split = str_split($b);

        if ($split[$c] == 5)
        {
            echo $b . ',';
        }
    }
}
```

It's result is :

```
 5,15,25,35,45,50,51,52,53,54,55,55,56,57,58,59,65,75,85,95,
```

But I want remove the final comma and get the last value.

Comment: use echo ltrim(','.$b) or rtrim(',',$b);

Comment: store in an array then use `implode()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Changes done.

**1.** Defined `$result=array();`;

**2.** Stored values in an array `$result[]= $b;`

**3.** Imploded an array with `,` `$result=  implode(",", $result);`

[PHP code demo](https://eval.in/762399)

```
<?php

$b = 1;
$ab = 100;
$result=array();

for ($b; $b < $ab; $b++)
{
    $len = strlen($b);
    $c = 0;
    for ($c; $c < $len; $c++)
    {
        $split = str_split($b);

        if ($split[$c] == 5)
        {
            $result[]= $b;
        }
    }
}
$lastElement =end($result);//last element
$result=  implode(",", $result);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: also add some explanation, will help to future visitors

Answer (score 1):

There is two way .Either you use all value in a array or **explode** the string into **array** 
1st way is

```
$b = 1;
    $ab = 100;
    $arr=[];

    for($b; $b < $ab; $b++){
        $len = strlen($b);
        $c = 0;
        for($c; $c < $len; $c++){
            $split = str_split($b);

            if($split[$c] == 5){
                $arr[]=$b;//push value into the array
            }
       }  
    }
     echo implode(",",$arr);//create string from array
    echo end($arr);// return the last value of a array
```

2nd way is

```
$b = 1;
    $ab = 100;
    $str="";

    for($b; $b < $ab; $b++){
        $len = strlen($b);
        $c = 0;
        for($c; $c < $len; $c++){
            $split = str_split($b);

            if($split[$c] == 5){
              $str .=$b .','; //create a string with name str
            }
       }  
    }
    $str=rtrim($str,','); //remove last comma of this string
    echo $str;
    $arr=explode(",",$str);//convert string to array
    echo end($arr);//return the last value of this array
```

Answer (score 1):

### Every other answer is too inefficient because they are using `str_split()` in an inner `for()` loop to build the array.

Echoing your values and concatenating with a comma each time will require you to write a separate condition to handle the commas.  This will just make your code messy.  Best practice would be to store all of the values in an array, then use `implode()` to glue them together with commas -- this avoids the unwanted trailing comma.  `end()` is the best way to extract the last value.

Here is a faster way (because it avoids unnecessary loops and function calls) to dynamically build your array, convert it to a csv string, and access the latest element in the array:

Code:

```
$d="5";                          // must be declared as string for strpos()
$x11=$d*11;                      // set only duplicate occurrence in range
for($x=1; $x<100; ++$x){
    if(strpos($x,$d)!==false){   // if at least one $d is found
        $array[]=$x;
        if($x==$x11){            // if two $d are found in integer
            $array[]=$x;
        }
    }
}
echo implode(',',$array),"<br>Last number: ",end($array);  // display
```

Output:

```
5,15,25,35,45,50,51,52,53,54,55,55,56,57,58,59,65,75,85,95
Last number: 95
```

This method makes 99 iterations, and 99 `strpos()` calls, and 20 comparisons to achieve the desired result.
Compare this to all other codes on this page, which make 99 outer loop iterations, 99 `strlen()` calls, 189 inner loop iterations, 189 `str_split()` calls, and 189 comparisons.

---

*faster still would be to remove the comparison inside of the `strpos()` block, add the `x11` value to the array outside of the loop, then sort the array before displaying.  Like this:

Code:

```
$d="5";                          // must be declared as string for strpos()
$array[]=$d*11;                  // store only duplicate occurrence in range
for($x=1; $x<100; ++$x){
    if(strpos($x,$d)!==false){   // if at least one $d is found
        $array[]=$x;
    }
}
sort($array);
echo implode(',',$array),"<br>Last number: ",end($array);  // display
```

---

Here is alternative method that uses functional iteration:

Code:

```
$d=5;
$array=array_filter(range(1,99),function($v)use($d){return strpos($v,(string)$d)!==false;})+[$d*11];
sort($array);  // zero-index the keys and position the appended value
echo implode(',',$array),"<br>Last number: ",end($array);  // display
```

Output:

```
5,15,25,35,45,50,51,52,53,54,55,55,56,57,58,59,65,75,85,95
Last number: 95
```

Answer (score 0):

Use rtrim then explode to get an array.

```
 $b = 1;
 $ab = 100;

 for($b; $b < $ab; $b++){
    $len = strlen($b);
    $c = 0;
    for($c; $c < $len; $c++){
       $split = str_split($b);

       if($split[$c] == 5){
          echo $b .','; 
       }
    }  
 }

 $b = rtrim(',',$b);
 $b = explode(',',$b);
 $b = $b[count($b)-1];
```

Comment: Posted my answer below

Answer (score 0):

This removes the last coma AND gives you the last value (as a string). You can always change the string back into an integer.

```
$b = 1;
$ab = 100;
$string = "";

for($b; $b < $ab; $b++){
    $len = strlen($b);
    $c = 0;
    for($c; $c < $len; $c++){
        $split = str_split($b);

        if($split[$c] == 5){
           $string .= $b .','; 
        }
   }  
}

$string = trim($string,",");
$pos = strripos($string,",");
echo substr($string,$pos + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

simply define a last variable:

```
$b = 1;
$ab = 100;
$last = 0;
for($b; $b < $ab; $b++){
    $len = strlen($b);
    $c = 0;
    for($c; $c < $len; $c++){
        $split = str_split($b);

        if($split[$c] == 5){
           if($last > 0){
               echo ',';
           }
           echo $b; 
           $last = $b;
        }
   }  
}
```

put the last value every time in `$last`.

and for coma, it checks if `$last > 0` put coma before `$b`

Answer (score 0):

You can also user these codes. Tested it and it worked.

```
$b = 1;
$ab = 100;
$hasValue = false;
for($b; $b < $ab; $b++){
    $hasFive = false;
    $len = strlen($b);
    $c = 0;
    for($c; $c < $len; $c++){
        $split = str_split($b);

        if($split[$c] == 5){
            $hasFive = true; 
        }
    } 

  if (!$hasValue && $hasFive) {
      echo $b;
      $hasValue = true;
   }else if($hasFive){
      echo ','.$b;
   }
}
```